# Rmarkdown unable to locate lua filter when knitting to word

Tags: r, lua, ms-word, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to knit some R markdown code to word at work. After updating all of my packages, I am unable to create any word documents. The error that I am getting is:

```
"C:~/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS TestDoc.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output TestDoc.docx --highlight-style tango --reference-doc word-styles.docx --lua-filter "\\~R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" 
Error running filter \\?\UNC\~/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua:
\\?\UNC\~/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted
```

Because I am not an administrator of the network at work, I am unable to go into the files to see if the lua filter is there. Is there anyway to get around this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you also in a environment with limited rights. I could solve it through the following steps:

1. uninstall rmarkdown in R-Studio with `remove.packages('rmarkdown')` (without admin rights).
2. get tech support to start an instance of R-Studio with admin rights.
3. uninstall rmarkdown in R-Studio with admin rights `remove.packages('rmarkdown')`.
4. installing rmarkdown again in R-Studio with admin rights `install.packages('rmarkdown')`.

Now the package rmarkdown and all its files are stored under C:/Programm Files... and not in your user folder and can be found during the knitting process.

Don't know if there is a way of solving this problem without admin rights. I'm guessing it would mean to change something manually in the rmarkdown files and maybe even recompiling the package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It really helped.

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer.